# Hover on mobile and tablet

Tags: css

I am making a responsive web design and my navigation menu has :hover links. I've tested them on desktop, ipad (tablet) , galaxy s3 (mobile) and iPhone (mobile) and it doesn't seem to have any issue. Upon clicking the link, the menu displays as if it is a click event. This is the way I want it to work and its working the way I want it to.

I came across many articles about how not to use :hover and they mostly ask to use the :focus and :active as well whenever a :hover is used.

So the question is, do I really need to add the :focus and :active whenever a :hover is in place so that it works on all tablet and mobile devices? I haven't uploaded the site yet as I want to make sure it is working great before I upload.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to consider accessibility of your page/app and touch gestures.
Take a look at this short video by Google dev advocate about touch in Web App.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rwc4fHUnGuU

Comment: Thanks, so basically whenever an :hover is being used, i also add a :focus and :active? eg; #link a:hover, #link a:focus, #link a:active {css goes here} Like this?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to group these selectors and apply the same styling for all states. You can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/4p6c9/ also. The only important thing is to have some styling when user hover over an element(e.g. link) , hit tab to focus on a link etc.

Comment: The video is unhelpful.